# Silverlight Telerik Chart click event value as Command parameter

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik Silverlight RadChart and I would like to capture the ItemClick event when the use clicks on one of the bars and pass the underlying value through to a ViewModel using a MVVMLight RelayCommand.

The problem I have is that I do not know how to pass through the value to the CommandParameter.

XAML

```
<telerik:RadChart x:Name="Chart" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConcernsCounts}">
    <telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
        <telerik:SeriesMapping>
            <telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                <telerik:BarSeriesDefinition ShowItemToolTips="True" />
            </telerik:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
            <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="ConcernsCount" DataPointMember="LegendLabel"/>
            <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="BusinessUnit" DataPointMember="XCategory"/>
            <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="ConcernsCount" DataPointMember="Label"/>
            <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="ConcernsCount" DataPointMember="YValue"/>
        </telerik:SeriesMapping>
    </telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
    <telerik:RadChart.DefaultView>
        <telerik:ChartDefaultView>
            <telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartTitle>
                <telerik:ChartTitle Content="PLM Concerns By Business Unit" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                           
            </telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartTitle>
            <telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartLegend>
                <telerik:ChartLegend x:Name="ChartLegend" UseAutoGeneratedItems="True" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartLegend>                   
            <telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartArea>
                <telerik:ChartArea LegendName="ChartLegend" Name="BusinessChartArea">
                    <telerik:ChartArea.AxisX>
                        <telerik:AxisX LabelRotationAngle="45"/>
                    </telerik:ChartArea.AxisX>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ItemClick">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadDetails}" CommandParameter="{Binding ?????? />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </telerik:ChartArea>
            </telerik:ChartDefaultView.ChartArea>
        </telerik:ChartDefaultView>
    </telerik:RadChart.DefaultView>
</telerik:RadChart>
```

I can capture the event in the code behind but would prefer to do the task declaritively

Code Behind

```
Partial Public Class ConcernsView
    Inherits Page

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()


        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        AddHandler Chart.DefaultView.ChartArea.ItemClick, Sub(s, e) stopMe(s, e)
    End Sub

    'Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Function stopMe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting.ChartItemClickEventArgs) As Object
        Dim sss As String
        sss = e.DataPoint.XCategory
        Stop
    End Function

End Class
```

Any idea of how to do this in the Command binding??

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Does setting PassEventArgsToCommand="True" work for your needs? For example:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="ItemClick">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadDetails}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

If you don't want to have a reference to the Telerik assemblies where ever your ViewModel is defined, you can use a handler using a dynamic instead of an object like this:

```
public void MyCommandHandler(dynamic args) { }
```

I use this trick to keep my projects "clean."  Now you can call whatever you need on the args without having to reference anything "Telerik."